# PHP - How can I insert the new filenames of uploading to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing the upload multimage files  and rename it successfully.
However, I don't know, How to get the name of file that I rename it with function move_uploaded_file().  I want to get the newname to insert to mySQL

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $count=count($_FILES["images"]["name"]);


    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {   
         if ((($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] < 100000))
        {

             if ($_FILES["images"]["error"][$i]  > 0)
             {
             echo "File Error : " . $_FILES["images"]["error"][$i]  . "<br />";
              }
              else 
             {
             // echo "Upload File Name: " . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]  . "<br />";
            // echo "File Type: " . $_FILES["images"]["type"][$i]  . "<br />";
              //echo "File Size: " . ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i]  / 1024) . " Kb<br />"; 

               if (file_exists("images/location/".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] ))
              {
               echo "<b>".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]  . " already exists. </b>";
               }
              else
              {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i] ,"images/location/"."NEW_NAME!!!".$i.".jpg" );
              //  echo "Stored in: " . "images/location/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i] ."<br />";
               ?>

              <?php
              }
              }
              }else
             {
              echo "Invalid file detail ::<br> file type ::".$_FILES["images"]["type"][$i] ." ,    file    size::: ".$_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] ;
              } 
            }
               }
```

..

```
       <form action = "" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="images[]" size="20" />
            <input type="file" name="images[]" size="20" />
            <input type="file" name="images[]" size="20" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
       </form>
```

Comment: 'test_file.'_'.'$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]

Comment: that's the old name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this in my project

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
$name = round(microtime(true)) . substr(md5(rand()), 0, 4) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $name);
//this is for single image upload
//Here $name is the new image name. You can then use your mysql_insert function to insert new image name to the database

//to upload multiple file just pass the file name as an array,tmp_name as an array
public function __attachments_upload($name, $tmp_name) {
    foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
        $temp = explode(".", $value);
        $name = round(microtime(true)) . substr(md5(rand()), 0, 4) . '.' . end($temp);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[$key], $name);
        //here you can use mysql_insert 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I insert once time?  I have 3 column in mysql (pic1, pic2, pic3)

Comment: do you have fixed image, like 3 ? 
If yes then create a function using first 3 lines of the answer and call it  for every image.

Or you can pass your image array to the __attachment_upload function

Comment: If you think the answer is okay, can you please accept the answer